# kendoDropDownList not scrolling to current value when datasource is array

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a `kendoDropDownList` in a `kendoGrid` inline editor:

```
matTypeDropDownEditor: (container, options) => {
    const model = options.model;
    $('<input id="materialType" required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField: "MaterialTypeName",
            dataValueField: "MaterialTypeID",
            //dataSource: materialTypeData,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/materials/materialtypes/' + model.OrganisationID,
                    }
                }
            },
```

If the datasource is an array `materialTypeData = []` pre-populated on page load, when editing the row the dropdownlist doesn't scroll to the current value. The correct item is selected but it isn't visible until clicking on the dropdown.

[image: On Edit]  [image: On Click]

If, as in the example above, I change the datasource to pull the items from the server it works correctly but obviously would require a round trip to the server every time a row is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Ok resolved it. When the data is local setting `autoBind: true` [as per the docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/autobind) will correctly display the selected item.

```
matTypeDropDownEditor: (container, options) => {
    const model = options.model;
    $('<input id="materialType" required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: true,
            dataTextField: "MaterialTypeName",
            dataValueField: "MaterialTypeID",
            dataSource: { data: materialTypeData },
```